# Moving an object to another class with adding a variable C#

Tags: c#, class

I need to completely transfer objects of one class to another by adding a new variable and its value.
For clarity, here's the first class:

```
class FirstClass
    {
        int id { get; set; }
        string name { get; set; }
        string password { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the second class:

```
class SecondClass
    {
        int id { get; set; }
        string name { get; set; }
        string password { get; set; }

        string note { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to do something like:

```
FirstClass first = new FirstClass() { id = 1, name = "name", password = "pass"};
SecondClass second = new SecondClass(first) { note = "text" };
```

Comment: You might want to consider changing `SecondClass` to be *composed* of a note and a `FirstClass`. But either way, just create a `SecondClass` constructor accepting a `FirstClass` parameter and doing the right thing with it. (As an aside, I'd very strongly suggest you read up on and start following .NET naming conventions.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create classes in a similar way:

```
class FirstClass
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
class SecondClass
    {
        public FirstClass element { get; set; }
        public string note { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the code for how to work with it:

```
List<FirstClass> firstarray = new List<FirstClass>();
List<SecondClass> secondarray = new List<SecondClass>();

private void work()
        {
            firstarray.Add(new FirstClass() { id = 1, name = "name", password = "text" });
            firstarray.Add(new FirstClass() { id = 2, name = "name", password = "text" });

            foreach (var item in firstarray)
            {
                if (item.id == 1)
                {
                    secondarray.Add(new SecondClass() { element = item, note = "text" });
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in secondarray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.element.id);
            }
        }
```